# Why I'm getting Functions are not valid as a React child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, warnings

**Here is QuoteScreen component, could anyone please tell me why I'm getting Functions are not valid as a React child warning?**

I understand this is a warning and app is running pretty fine with it. But this is annoying me and I would like to get rid of the warning. Please take a look what is going wrong here.

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import Greetings from './Greetings';

export default class QuoteScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      quote: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 30,
      },
      alignRight: {
        textAlign: 'right',
      },
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Greetings name={this.state.name} />
        <Text>{this.state.quote.content}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.alignRight}>
          {this.state.quote.author ? ' - ' + this.state.quote.author : ''}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.storeData();
    this.getData();
    this.fetchQuote().then(response => {
      this.setState({quote: response});
    });
  }

  storeData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('user_name', 'Simon Gomes');
    } catch (e) {
      // saving error
    }
  };
  getData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_name');
      if (value !== null) {
        // value previously stored
        this.setState({name: value});
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // error reading value
    }
  };

  fetchQuote = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch('https://api.quotable.io/random');
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      return responseJson;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Not sure why there're warnings, but I think at least you need this fix: `constructor(props) { super(props);`

Comment: what is Greetings? is it a class or a function?

Comment: @GauravRoy Class  

```import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

export default class Greetings extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>
        <Greet /> {this.props.name}!
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

const Greet = () => {
  let userTime = new Date().getHours();
  if (userTime < 12) {
    return 'Good morning';
  } else if (userTime < 18) {
    return 'Good afternoon';
  } else {
    return 'Good evening';
  }
};
```

Comment: @MarsonMao I don't think that's necessary!

Comment: can you post the whole error once?

Comment: Greet is a function, I think this warning comes from there, can you try commenting it out to see if then the warning is gone?

Comment: @Konstantin I'm pretty sure it is not coming from there buddy.

Comment: Well, this component is not using props at all, so it might be fine, but I dont think skipping passing the props to super gains any advantage? Anyway it's just a good convention, it's also noted in the official document. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: Well maybe it is, buddy

Comment: @Konstantin and MarsonMao I would appreciate if you could provide constructive and logical solutions rather posting stuff what you think (a maybe type thing) and what comes in your mind. I understand clearly what should I do with props and constructor. Anyways thank you for trying, got rid of the warning using Gaurav's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the error, its inside the greetings class, you have used greet a function in your render method and thats not allowed ,

```
const Greet = () => { let userTime = new Date().getHours(); if (userTime < 12) { return 'Good morning'; } else if (userTime < 18) { return 'Good afternoon'; } else { return 'Good evening'; } };
```

you have to use greet like  ,

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {this.Greet()}
        </View>
    )
}
```

> and inside Greet function ,
>  you have to return strings as  `<Text>GoodMorning</Text>` instead of just `'Good Morning'`

Hope that helps, just ask if any doubts

Comment: Thank you brother. This was a winner :). Just one point I believe using ```<Greet />``` is fine but I had to return ```<Text>Good Morning</Text>``` from the function. Thank you, warning is gone, cheers.